# Keras NN - domain name rank guessing ( loss = nan )

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I'm new to neural networks and I'm trying to create a model which guesses rank/value of domain names. I have a list of domains with their rank (from 10 to 4.9).

The first, I'm adding some metrics like number of vowels etc.

But then when the model is training, it shows loss: nan and accuracy: 0.000 after the first epoch. I'm not sure where is the problem. I'll appreciate any advices. I guess one of the problems is that my output isn't binary.

```
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
import pandas as pd
import sklearn as sklearn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tld

TOP_DOMAINS_PATH = 'domainrank.csv'
domains_df = pd.read_csv(TOP_DOMAINS_PATH, nrows=100000)

# add features
domains_df['tld'] = domains_df['Domain'].apply(lambda x: tld.get_tld(x, fix_protocol=True,fail_silently=True))
domains_df['sld'] = domains_df['Domain'].apply(lambda x: getattr(tld.get_tld(x, fix_protocol=True, as_object=True,fail_silently=True),'domain',None))
domains_df['dots'] = domains_df['sld'].str.count('\.')
domains_df['vowels_count'] = domains_df['sld'].str.count('[aeiouy]')
domains_df['cons_count'] = domains_df['sld'].str.lower().str.count(r'[a-z]') - domains_df['vowels_count']
domains_df['length'] = domains_df['sld'].str.len()
domains_df['rank_normalized'] = domains_df['Open Page Rank'].apply(lambda x: x/10)

# remove not used columns
domains_df.pop('Open Page Rank')
domains_df.pop('Domain')
domains_df.pop('tld')
domains_df.pop('sld')

dataset = domains_df.values
X = dataset[:, 0:len(domains_df.columns) - 1, ]
Y = dataset[:, len(domains_df.columns) - 1]

min_max_scaler = sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
X_scale = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X)
X_train, X_val_and_test, Y_train, Y_val_and_test = train_test_split(X_scale, Y, test_size=0.3)
X_val, X_test, Y_val, Y_test = train_test_split(X_val_and_test, Y_val_and_test, test_size=0.5)

model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(5,)),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
])

model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
          batch_size=32, epochs=100,
          validation_data=(X_val, Y_val))
```

After modifying `domains_df` it looks like this:

```
       dots  vowels_count  cons_count  length  rank_normalized
0       0.0           1.0         4.0     5.0             1.00
1       0.0           4.0         4.0     8.0             1.00
2       0.0           2.0         5.0     7.0             1.00
3       0.0           5.0         2.0     7.0             1.00
4       0.0           3.0         3.0     6.0             1.00
     ...           ...         ...     ...              ...
99995   0.0           2.0         2.0     4.0             0.49
99996   0.0           6.0        10.0    18.0             0.49
99997   0.0           4.0         4.0     8.0             0.49
99998   0.0           6.0        10.0    16.0             0.49
99999   0.0           3.0         7.0    10.0             0.49
```

And output from training:

```
Epoch 1/100
   32/70000 [..............................] - ETA: 2:05 - loss: 0.6929 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
 3264/70000 [>.............................] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.6911 - accuracy: 3.0637e-04  
 6624/70000 [=>............................] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.6903 - accuracy: 3.0193e-04
10080/70000 [===>..........................] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.6899 - accuracy: 1.9841e-04
13472/70000 [====>.........................] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.6896 - accuracy: 1.4846e-04
16832/70000 [======>.......................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6895 - accuracy: 1.1882e-04
20384/70000 [=======>......................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6894 - accuracy: 9.8116e-05
23808/70000 [=========>....................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6892 - accuracy: 8.4005e-05
27328/70000 [==========>...................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6892 - accuracy: 1.0978e-04
30784/70000 [============>.................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6891 - accuracy: 9.7453e-05
34144/70000 [=============>................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6891 - accuracy: 1.1715e-04
37536/70000 [===============>..............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6890 - accuracy: 1.0656e-04
40992/70000 [================>.............] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 9.7580e-05   
44480/70000 [==================>...........] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 8.9928e-05
47968/70000 [===================>..........] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 8.3389e-05
51296/70000 [====================>.........] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 7.7979e-05
54688/70000 [======================>.......] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 7.3142e-05
58112/70000 [=======================>......] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 6.8833e-05
61440/70000 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 6.5104e-05
64832/70000 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 6.1698e-05
68288/70000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 5.8575e-05
70000/70000 [==============================] - 1s 18us/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 5.7143e-05 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/100
   32/70000 [..............................] - ETA: 3s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
 3392/70000 [>.............................] - ETA: 1s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
 6848/70000 [=>............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
10336/70000 [===>..........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
13792/70000 [====>.........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
17216/70000 [======>.......................] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
20544/70000 [=======>......................] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
23968/70000 [=========>....................] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
27456/70000 [==========>...................] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
30912/70000 [============>.................] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
34368/70000 [=============>................] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
37824/70000 [===============>..............] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
41280/70000 [================>.............] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
44672/70000 [==================>...........] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
48064/70000 [===================>..........] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
51392/70000 [=====================>........] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
54848/70000 [======================>.......] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
58208/70000 [=======================>......] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
61376/70000 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
64384/70000 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
67456/70000 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
70000/70000 [==============================] - 1s 17us/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/100
```

Comment: What is the shape and range of `Y`? You used `'sigmoid'`, which means the model expects `Y` range to be from 0 to 1. --- For `'binary_crossentropy'` to return `nan`, some weird thing happened such as 1 - received non numeric value; 2 - exploded or divided by zero (may happen with values out of the expected range); 3 - Had problems in the model's weights due to bad initialization, bad optimizer, bad custom loss, etc. (doesn't seem your case)

Comment: @DanielMöller It's the last column in domains_df - it's a list of floats from 4.9 to 10 so I divided it by 10 - it's 0.49 to 1.0.

Comment: @DanielMöller I used df.dropna() function and now it doesn't return NAN. But loss is allways around 0.68 which I suppose isn't good.

Comment: You won't get good results for "binary_crossentropy" if your values are not 0 and 1. It also doesn't make sense to have an accuracy if your problem is not classification. --- You can try `'mse'` or `'mae'` as losses, and if you use these losses, you could even remove the sigmoid.

Comment: You might want to add `BatchNormalization` layers before each "relu" and before "sigmoid", your model may be saturated because you're using non standardized values.